# Complex validation using Joi library

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I have this json:

```
let purchaseSubscription = {
  'metadata': {
    'eventName': 'PurchaseSubscription',
    'type': 'setup' // setup, repurchase or recurring
  },
  'data': {
    'subscriptionId': '447481',
    'subscriptionTrialId': '23542'
  }
};
```

If the **metadata.type** has value **setup**
then **data.subscriptionTrialId** should be validated for existence and to be a number.
If the **metadata.type** has other values, the **data.subscriptionTrialId** can be ignored.

This is what I currently have:

```
const Joi = require('joi');
const validTypes = ['setup', 'repurchase', 'recurring'];

exports.schema = Joi.object().keys({
  metadata: Joi.object({
    eventName: Joi.string().required(),
    type: Joi.string().valid(validTypes).required()
  }).required(),
  data: Joi.object({
    subscriptionId: Joi.number().integer().min(1).max(2147483647).required(),
    subscriptionTrialId: Joi.when(
        'metadata.type', { is: 'setup', then: Joi.required() })
  }).required()
}).options({ 'allowUnknown': true });
```

But I am not getting desired results. The **data.subscriptionTrialId** is always validated, no matter what I have under **metadata.type**

I tried reading [documentation](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v14.3.1/API.md#anywhencondition-options), but can't make it to work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `otherwise` key in the JOI schema.

Somewhere in your code before declaring `exports.schema`:

```
const trialIdRequired = Joi.object({
    subscriptionId: Joi.number().integer().min(1).max(2147483647).required(),
    subscriptionTrialId: Joi.required()
  }).required()

const trialIdNotRequired = Joi.object({
   subscriptionId: Joi.number().integer().min(1).max(2147483647).required(),
    subscriptionTrialId: Joi.any()
})
```

And then add a `when` clause to the `data` field

```
data: Joi.when(
        'metadata.type', 
        { 
            is: 'setup', 
            then: trialIdRequired,
            otherwise: trialIdNotRequired
        })
```

Comment: I plugged your example to the code, and for some reason it does not get validated at all, in other words it is ignored. Would you care to expand the answer, where I can see exactly what is going on? I have a feeling I am doing something silly :(

Comment: Oops my bad!
Apparently Joi does not read siblings of parent in the `when` clause.
Updating the answer to the alternate solution.

Comment: Worked great. Thank you.